# Mapr pig throwing error

Tags: apache-pig

if I use following load command
 `A = LOAD '/home/mapr/resoucr' using PigStorage(',');`

It throws following error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - io.bytes.per.checksum is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.bytes-per-checksum
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the deprecation warnings. Possibly you are lacking in newer hadoop  configuration.

To get rid of this, you need to update your hadoop configuration files.

Comment: what are the files to be updated ? I'm using MapR sand box  5.1.0 version.